# find words longer than 15 characters in a column

Tags: oracle

I have a table named `SIRKET` and two columns named `sirket_unvan` and `cust_id`. I want to find words in `sirket_unvan` which are longer than 15 characters.

I use

```
select sirket_unvan from SIRKET where cust_id=0
```

But how can find word which are longer than 15 characters? I would like to report those words to another column. ı think ı should write procedure. And one line can be has 2 or more words which has longer than 15 characters

```
 cust_id |sirket_unvan
---------+----------------------------------------------
  0      | sdsd Afdfdgfdgdgdg fdgfgfgf fgfgf           
  0      | dfdfds dffd dsfdffggfdgfdgfdgfgdgdfgd fdfdfd
  0      | sdfsdfsdf dsfdsfdsfdsdgfgfgf               
  0      | sdfsdfsd sdfsdfsdf
  1      | sdfsdfsdf dsfdsfdsfdsdgfgfgf 
  2      | dsfdsfs sdfsdfsdgfhfh
```

I want this output

```
   cust_id   | sirket_unvan                                |longerthan15characterwords
    ---------+---------------------------------------------+---------------------------
      0      | sdsd Afdfdgfdgdgdg fdgfgfgf fgfgf           | Afdfdgfdgdgdg
      0      | dfdfds dffd dsfdffggfdgfdgfdgfgdgdfgd fdfdfd| dsfdffggfdgfdgfdgfgdgdfgd
      0      | sdfsdfsdf dsfdsfdsfdsdgfgfgf                | dsfdsfdsfdsdgfgfgf
```

Comment: You tagged the question with MySQL **and** Oracle. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: it is important ? mysql and oracle select serach same ı think?

Comment: ı think you give -1 my question but my other questin ı said only oracle other people made problem this.

Comment: I really don't want to seem harsh but your english isn't very understandable. This may cause some issues for somebody that would like to help you.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL are *very* different. And no, I did not downvote your question - although I can understand why it was done. Because on of the possible reasons for downvoting would be: "*this question does not show any research effort*"

Comment: yes it is different at triger or other procedure but their select search same ı think. I update my question. if you dont understand some part you can said to me. ı will changed it. I am not english. so as ı know my english bad but ı put ı wanted output

Comment: @ADKu: I edited your question. Please note that it's not *colon*, but *column*. Colon means either this -->  `:` or intestine in English.

Comment: @Benoit thanks a lot ı hope my question will be more understable:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all words in your column, you will have to write an SQL function. Otherwise, regular expressions can catch the first and last 15-character words in a line.

### With an SQL function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function wordslongerthan(line IN VARCHAR2, threshold IN NUMBER)
return varchar2 deterministic
is
   first_location INTEGER := 0;
   tmp_line VARCHAR2(4000);
   word VARCHAR2(4000);
begin
   first_location := REGEXP_INSTR(line, '\S{' || to_char(threshold) || '}');
   if first_location = 0 then return null; end if;

   tmp_line := SUBSTR(line, first_location);
   first_location := REGEXP_INSTR(tmp_line, '\s');
   if first_location = 0 then return tmp_line; end if;

   word := SUBSTR(tmp_line, 1, first_location-1);
   tmp_line := SUBSTR(tmp_line, first_location);
   return word || ' ' || wordslongerthan(tmp_line, threshold);
end;
/

SELECT sirket_unvan, cust_id, wordslongerthan(sirket_unvan, 15)
  FROM sirket
 WHERE cust_id = 0 AND regexp_instr(sirket_unvan, '\S{15}') > 0 ;
```

### With regular expressions:

`\S{15,}` selects any 15 or more non-whitespace consecutive characters.

Therefore you can find the last word longer than 15 characters like this:

```
SELECT sirket_unvan,
       cust_id,
       regexp_replace(sirket_unvan, '(.*\s|^)(\S{15,}).*', '\2')
  FROM sirket
 WHERE cust_id = 0
   AND regexp_instr(sirket_unvan, '\S{15}') > 0 ;
```

[image: capture]

The first capture group (`(.*\s|^)`) matches anything up to a whitespace character, or at start of string; the second capture group is what you want (hence the backreference as third argument), and the rest is matched with `.*` so that it disappears from the replaced expression.

And you can find the first word like this:

```
SELECT sirket_unvan,
       cust_id,
       regexp_substr(sirket_unvan, '\S{15,}')
  FROM sirket
 WHERE cust_id = 0
   AND regexp_instr(sirket_unvan, '\S{15}') > 0 ;
```

[image: capture]

Comment: no it not work. it copies all of lines to regexp_replace columns.. it dont give only word

Comment: yes it is work but it find one word which longer 15 character. some lines has 2 word which has longer than 15 character.

Comment: it do not find 2 word at same line which longer 15 character

Comment: yes you said true ı have to write function but function writing is difficult for me.. :(  ı could not write function

Comment: ı will be very glad if you helped me for writng function

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select cust_id , sirket_unvan, sirket_unvan1 from (
SELECT DISTINCT cust_id ,
          SIRKET_UNVAN,
          REGEXP_SUBSTR(SIRKET_UNVAN , '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, LEVEL) SIRKET_UNVAN1
FROM MY_TABLE9
CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR(SIRKET_UNVAN , '[[:alpha:]]+', 1, LEVEL)  IS NOT NULL)
WHERE LENGTH(SIRKET_UNVAN1) > 15;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     select sirket_unvan from SIRKET where length(sirket_unvan)>15
```

Comment: lengh do you mean lenght?

Comment: hımm yes it find it but have can ı show this longer words other colon?